# Unclear on use of "fromIndex" in "indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)"

Tags: java, variables, indexof

I'm trying to use *indexOf* method in the second line written below, to do that as you know you need to put an integer after coma, but in my case I don't want to put an actual integer, I want to put an integer variable. (*guessedLetter* variable is a String variable that I have defined previously)

```
int aaa=bookTitle.indexOf(guessedLetter);
int bbb=bookTitle.indexOf(guessedLetter,aaa);
```

If I type the code in this way, It doesn't function properly. But if I type the code like written below;

```
int bbb=bookTitle.indexOf(guessedLetter,5);
```

it works. So you need to use an actual integer, but as I said I need to use an integer variable instead.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: 5 was just an example, I'm not looking for a certain number. aaa varies all the time.

Comment: What does "It doesn't function properly" mean? Show example in/output, both expected and what you're actually getting.

Comment: It supposed to returns the index within bookTitle string of the first occurrence of the specified character, starting the search at the specified index. But if I type a variable, it doesnt start the search at the specified index, in a way it doesn't take that variable as an integer.

Comment: The code the way it's posted works just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. As you can see in the answer I needed to increment the starting index at least by one. So the reason that I was failing was that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `char` is found at `aaa` position, to find more occurrences of it you have to increment the starting index at least by one:

```
int bbb=bookTitle.indexOf(guessedLetter,aaa + 1);
```

otherwise you go on finding the same `char` in the same position.